# Oracle SQL Merge query to fix the data integrity issue

Tags: oracle

```
create table abc
(
job_id integer
,etl_job_run_day date
,cust_sid integer
,cust_id number(38,0)
,cust_first_name varchar2(100)
,cust_last_name varchar2(100)
,effective_dt_from date
,effective_dt_to date
,version integer
,latest_fl varchar2(1)
,actual_cust_id integer
);

insert into abc values (123,01.01.2020,100,6842,'Tony','Greig',10.01.2020 00:00:00,31.12.2199 23:59:59,1,'Y','');
insert into abc values (123,01.01.2020,123,6842,'Tony','Greig',10.01.2020 00:00:00,31.12.2199 23:59:59,1,'Y',9011);
```

```
JOB_ID  ETL_JOB_RUN_DAY    CUST_SID CUST_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME CUST_LAST_NAME   EFFECTIVE_DATE_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO    VERSION LATEST_FL ACTUAL_CUST_ID
123 01.01.20 00:00:00  100      6842    Tony        Greig        10.01.00 00:00:00     31.12.99 23:59:59    1   Y   
123 15.01.20 00:00:00  148      6842    Tony        Greig        10.01.00 00:00:00     31.12.99 23:59:59    1   Y     9011
```

so this is wrong due to some wrong historical data update so the expected values should be like this

```
JOB_ID  ETL_JOB_RUN_DAY    CUST_SID CUST_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME CUST_LAST_NAME   EFFECTIVE_DATE_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO    VERSION LATEST_FL ACTUAL_CUST_ID
123 01.01.20 00:00:00  100      6842    Tony        Greig        01.01.00 00:00:00     15.01.20 00:00:00    1   N   
123 15.01.20 00:00:00  148      6842    Tony        Greig        15.01.20 00:00:00     31.12.99 23:59:59    2   Y     9011
```

Comment: Hallo, what is the exact question?

Comment: I need to come up with a merge statement on order to fix the data integrity issues , points to remember, since i have this data inconsistent data for many records i hav e to come up with a merge  statement to fix this

Comment: I need to come up with a merge statement on order to fix the data integrity issues , points to remember, since i have this data inconsistent data for many records i hav e to come up with a merge  statement to fix this

Comment: Please reduce your example to 2-3 columns where you show what change of data you want to archive. With merge statements there are 2 issues. 1st get the added data. 2nd correct writing of the statement with on and update part. In which part should we help?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that we need some primary key to clearly define the order of rows. We need to compare previous and next rows and for that an order is elementary. If we can use `job_id, etl_job_run_day, cust_sid` for that then you can find problematic rows using this query:

```
select * 
  from (
    select job_id, etl_job_run_day, cust_sid, effective_dt_from edf, effective_dt_to edt, version, latest_fl, 
           lag(latest_fl)  over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) prev_fl,
           lead(latest_fl) over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) next_fl,
           lag(effective_dt_to)  over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) prev_edt,
           lead(effective_dt_to) over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) next_edt,
           lead(etl_job_run_day) over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) next_run
      from abc
      where latest_fl = 'Y' )
  where edt in (prev_edt, next_edt)
```

Please test it, if OK, you can use above query as source table in `merge`:

```
merge into abc a
using (
    select * 
      from (
        select job_id, etl_job_run_day, cust_sid, effective_dt_from edf, effective_dt_to edt, version, latest_fl, 
               lag(latest_fl)  over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) prev_fl,
               lead(latest_fl) over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) next_fl,
               lag(effective_dt_to)  over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) prev_edt,
               lead(effective_dt_to) over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) next_edt,
               lead(etl_job_run_day) over (partition by job_id order by etl_job_run_day, cust_sid) next_run
          from abc
          where latest_fl = 'Y' )
      where edt in (prev_edt, next_edt)) s
on (a.job_id = s.job_id and a.etl_job_run_day = s.etl_job_run_day and a.cust_sid = s.cust_sid)
when matched then update set 
    a.latest_fl = case when next_fl = 'Y' then 'N' else a.latest_fl end,
    a.effective_dt_to   = case when next_fl = 'Y' and  next_edt = a.effective_dt_to 
                                then next_run
                                else a.effective_dt_to end,
    a.effective_dt_from = case when prev_fl = 'Y' and  prev_edt = a.effective_dt_to 
                                then etl_job_run_day
                                else a.effective_dt_to end, 
    version = case when prev_fl = 'Y' then version + 1 else version end
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d8e38550b4cb9a96cc51aa3ef8cf593b)</sup>**

This gave me requested values for your (corrected) sample data. Again, please test it. Make a copy if possible. If you have more than two positions in a row and there is always same version there, you will need additional merge, but in this case all following versions should be increased? You can do it using `count() over (order by...)` in next similiar `merge`.

Comment: i have tried using the above query but it is not working this is the query which used to identify the data integrity issue SELECT * from
(SELECT *
--cust_sid, version, effective_dt_from, effective_dt_to, cust_id
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               LEAD(effective_dt_from, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY actual_cust_id ORDER BY effective_dt_from) AS next_date,
               LEAD(version, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY actual_cust_id ORDER BY effective_dt_from) AS next_version
          FROM abc a
          )
WHERE effective_dt_to != next_date
 or version = next_version); - i go 100 rows